# Find the number of zeros of $f$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Suppose we have $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $f''=-|f|$ with $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$. How many zeros does $f$ have? How to change the initial conditions to make $f$ be an odd function.

For the first question, let $f'=z$, $z'=-|f|$. we can verify the Lipschitz condition. Then by Picard's Theorem, we conclude it has a unique solution. Moreover, if $z(x)=f(-x)$, then $z''(x)=f''(-x)=-|f(-x)|=-|z(x)|$. Then $z=f$, so $f$ is even. I know we can list all possible situations to discuss the number of zeros of $f$, but I am not sure about that.

For the second question, I find $f''=-f$ with $f(0)=0,f'(0)=1$ can give an odd function $f$, and $f''=-f$ with $f(0)=1,f'(0)=0$ can give an even function $f$. So is it similar for $f''=-|f|$?

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first claim is wrong, $z'(0)=-f'(0)=-1$, so the initial values are different, $z\ne f$. You would get an even function if the IC were switched, $f(0)=1$, $f'(0)=0$. The initial conditions are already correct for an odd function, $f(0)=0$ is necessary, and any odd solution can be scaled so that $f'(0)=1$ or $f'(0)=-1$. With $z(x)=-f(-x)$ you get $z''(x)=-f''(-x)=|f(-x)|=|z(x)|$, so a different equation.

$f$ is strictly concave, so has at most 2 intersections with any line, including the $x$ axis. You can actually solve the equation, for $f(x)\ge 0$ the equation is the harmonic oscillator, so with the IC $f(x)=\sin x$ on $[0,\pi]$, with continuations $f(x)=\sinh(x)$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=-\sinh(x-\pi)$ for $x>\pi$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was wrong since I forgot to calculate the initial value. Then for the first question, $f$ has two zeros in total since it is concave down and $f'(0)=1$ is non-zero. And that $f$ are neither odd nor even, so these two zero are not symmetric with some vertical line right?

Comment: Yes, that all is true. Just notice that a concave function like $\ln(1+x)$ does not need to have a second root.

Comment: I am looking for a rigorous proof that $f$ has two zeros. One is clear $f(0)=0$. From  $f'(x)=\int_0^x f''(t)dt=-\int_0^x |f(t)|dt<0$, but $f'(0)=1$... there must be some mistakes...May I know how to find the other zero rigorously?

Comment: The second root is at $x=\pi$, the function is symmetric around $x=\pi/2$. You need to apply FTC correctly, it is $f'(x)=f'(0)+\int_0^xf''(t)\,dt$

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks.